# How to change change error messages on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My view:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <% if @product.errors.details[:amount].any? %>
            <div class="has-error">
              <%= f.label "#{t('product.shineer_irsen')}", class: 'control-label' %>
              <%= f.number_field :amount, value: 0, min: 0, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          <% else %>            
            <%= f.label "#{t('product.shineer_irsen')}", class: 'control-label' %>
            <%= f.number_field :amount, value: 0, min: 0, class: "form-control" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

I want to validate amount in input field and i want to change its error message into my native language.

Now, error message is
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cPwz.png)

How to change it? please help me.

Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :branch
    validates :amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}

    def item_name
        item.try(:name)
    end

    def item_name=(query)
        self.item = Item.find_by_name(query) if query.present?
    end

    def amount=(new_value)
        if read_attribute(:amount)
            @old_amount = read_attribute(:amount)
            write_attribute(:amount, new_value.to_i + @old_amount)
        else 
            write_attribute(:amount, new_value.to_i)
        end 
    end
end
```

some line of local/mn.yml

```
activerecord:
    attributes:
     ...
    errors:
      models:
        subcategory:
          attributes:
            category_id:
              invalid: "ahaha"
              blank: "хоосон байж болохгүй"
            category:
              blank: "сонгоогүй байна."
        product:
          attributes:
            amount:
              greater_than_or_equal_to: 'Оруулах утга 0-ээс их байх ёстой.'
```

Comment: You should validate in the Model

Comment: I did it.  In model : validates: amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}. But once i get error, http://localhost:3000/products/2/edit gets changed into http://localhost:3000/products/2. I have no show method in my controller . I deleted, cuz i dont need it So, there is some problem :)

Comment: Add your Model to the post, and I'll help you

Comment: I can't see the validation on your model, where is it?

Comment: Oh my bad i got that from backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to translate "Value must be grater than or equal to 0", if that's the case, what you need to do is create a translation for that on the locale file. In Spanish will be something like this:

```
# config/locales/es.yml
es:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        product:
          attributes:
            amount:
              greater_than_or_equal_to: 'What ever you want to say'
```

Depending on your native language, you have to create the file and define the message, I think you are doing it already, because you are using translations:

```
#{t('product.shineer_irsen')}
```

You can find more information here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: I tried. But didnt worked. Still getting same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the error message that you get from a model validation, in this case you need to add to your Model:

```
validates :age, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, message: 'Este campo tiene que ser positivo' }
```

With this, you dont need to change the view.

Comment: The validation is completely correct. but it's a better practice to put the message on the locale file instead of the model.

Comment: I suppose to my question is bad. I have to get greater than or equal to 0 value from input and i have to validate in model. i have to do both.

Comment: @CarlosCastillo I'm watching you answer, It is really good (definitely going to learn about translation for AR).

Comment: In model, with this
  def amount=(new_value) ...
    end
method, im adding input value into amount. If i dont validate in view, they can input some minus value. If that value is less than or equal to old amount value. i dont get error.

Comment: Is difficult to read code in a comment, post all the code in the question @TuvsheeZorigoo

Comment: Sorry. it's amount=(new_value) method of product model. i added it to question.

Comment: I just felt that error message is from Jquery. Is it?