# Simplifying multiple model validation error messages into a nicer sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I simplify an error message on model attributes validation like this:

`Categories can't be blank, Topics can't be blank`

Into this:

`Categories and Topics can't be blank`

Comment: Rails errors include both the full messages, and a more broken-down collection with the field names and default messages. I'd start there. That said: the UX should still be broken down on the form fields themselves, and an aggregated error sentence may not provide meaningful-enough feedback, even if it's in addition to field-level UX.

Comment: Look at your `config/locales/en.yml` file, you may be able to accomplish some of what you're wanting there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214372/how-to-change-change-error-messages-on-rails

Comment: Thank you very much to both, it looks like I need to alter the original messages, and create the full sentence myself based on the array of errors I receive

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper function that does that. Not pretty (and should definitely be improved) but to get you started something like

```
messages = "Categories can't be blank, Topics can't be blank, Bla can't be negative"

def split_and_combine(messages)
  parts = messages.split(',').map{|p| p.strip}.map do |p|
    i = p.index(' ')
    { base: p[0...i].strip, rest: p[i..].strip}
  end
  result = ''
  parts.each do |p|
    i = result.index(p[:rest])
    if i
      result = result.insert(i, "and #{p[:base]} ")
    else
      result = "#{p[:base]} #{p[:rest]}#{',' if result.length > 0} #{result}"
    end
  end
  result
end

puts split_and_combine messages
```

Would output

`Bla can't be negative, Categories and Topics can't be blank`